# Calling python script on MAC/Linux from Command line - passing arguments

Tags: python, linux, macos, command-line, batch-file

Consider this setup and folder structure:

```
c:\foo
      \bin\foo.bat
      \lib\foo.py
```

I have foo.bat path added to my environment PATH, so I can call it from anywhere passing in some arguments:

```
c:/>foo.bat -v
```

foo.bat contains this code:

```
@ECHO OFF
"c:\foo\lib\foo.py" %1 %2 %3 %4 %5 %6 %7 %8 %9
```

This works fine in Windows.

Now I want to be able to do the same in Mac or Linux.

How can I create this executable file, that will call the script lib\foo.py, passing in some arguments?

thanks

**[SOLUTION]**

thanks guys, your answers helped me end up with this script that works as intended:

in \foo\bin\foo *file*

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
python /usr/local/foo/lib/foo.py $*
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't explicitly say what your shell of choice is, but assuming it's GNU bash:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
/path/to/lib/foo.py $*
```

Note that both your shell script and foo.py need to have the execution bit set to be run this way (that is only a

```
chmod +x /path/to/your/script /path/to/lib/foo.py
```

away).

Comment: thanks Emanuele. That really helped as I wasn't sure how to pass in those arguments.

Answer (score 6):

You can call python scripts directly on mac/linux, just make sure to put your python interpreter on the first line, example file foo:

```
#!/usr/bin/python 
if __name__ == "__main__":
    print 'bar'
```

to run the file call it directly form your current directory using `./foo`

if you want to access if from everywhere you can put it in `/usr/local/bin`, for example, just make sure that the file is executable (`chmod +x foo`).

Comment: thank deif. The only problem is I didn't want the user to call in the script directly, as I was keeping all executables in the bin, while the script lives in the libs where it's got relative references to other libraries/scripts in that folder.